# Change List's type on a condition

Tags: c#, list, types

There is a string which can have multiple values:

`string myString = "class1";` or

```
string myString = "class2";
```

And there is a list, and I want to change its type based on the value of `myString`:

```
List</*unknown*/> myList = new List</*unknown*/>();
```

I have tried generating a type like this :

```
Type mytype = Type.GetType(myString);
```

Then I tried pasing `mytype` to List but it didn't work out.

How can I make Lists of a variable type which can change based a variable? Thanks.

EDIT :

I have two tables I want to use either one based on the value of `myString`. So if `myString` is `table1` I want to use  :

```
List<class1> myList = new List<class1>();
```

or if `myString` is `table2` I want to use

```
List<class2> myList = new List<class2>();
```

Comment: @Lemurr How should I initialize `myList` at first? Any type is ok?

Comment: The type must be known at compile-time for generics. You can't do it that way. Perhaps there is a better solution to your problem. Could you provide some more context?

Comment: @Pelle You *can* do it that way (see linked dupe) but you're right there is usually a better solution.

Comment: @Pelle I have edited the question and added some more about what I need. Thanks.